# Remove chapter number

Tags: numbering, chapters

Sorry for wrong question formatting, but I'm new here and I don't know the way around these tools.
I would like to know if there is a way to remove the chapter number from the document (preferably without any preamble lines).
For example, if I have:

```
\chapter{chap1}
\chapter{chap2}
   \section{sec1}
       \subsection{subsec1}
```

Then, sec1 has number `2.1` and subsec1 has number `2.1.1.` I would like the "2" removed, so I have `1.1` for subsec1 and `1` for sec1 in this particular chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no `preamble` command should be used, it has to be done inside the document body, redefining `\thesection` and later recall the old definition to restore it to the `1.1.1` etc. style.

Please note, that this leads to larger gaps in the `ToC`

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\let\origthesection\thesection % Store the old definition

\chapter{chap1}
\chapter{chap2}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} % Kick out the chapter number 
   \section{sec1}
       \subsection{subsec1}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\origthesection} % Restore to the old style
\chapter{chap 3}
   \section{sec1}
       \subsection{subsec1}

\end{document}
```

[image]